# How to use property values in JSONPath transfer

Tags: json, soapui, jsonpath

[JSONPath Property Transfer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSZRV.png)

I'm trying to use a property value in a JSONPath property transfer. Using the syntax ${#TestCase#PropName} doesn't seem to work as it does for XML/XQuery.

```
.search.price[?(@.farePrice[*].flightSeg[0].fareRef.id=='${#TestCase#PropName}')].uri[0]
```

An example path is above with the property variable but running this returns an error. Could anyone help here?

Comment: Would you mind showing the raw response?

Comment: I think the response is irrelevant, I'm just asking how to reference a property in the JSONPath transfer?

Comment: Not sure if there is any thing called JSONPath property transfer in soapui. Do you mean property transfer?

Comment: Yes it's a standard property transfer test step with path language set to JSONPath